# Why is a Intent started before an AlertDialog.Builder, even if it's coded the other way round

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-alertdialog

With the following code, the Intent is started when calling newPicture, and the Dialog is shown afterwards. What does this, and how can I change the order?

```
public void newPicture(View v) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean geoProtipAlreadyShown = settings.getBoolean("geoProtipAlreadyShown", false);

    if (!geoProtipAlreadyShown) {
        showGeoProtip();

        // and set the option in SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("geoProtipAlreadyShown", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // start the image capture activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);        
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH, "tmpfile.jpg")));
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);  

}

private void showGeoProtip() {
    String geoProtip = this.getResources().getString(R.string.protip);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(geoProtip).setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the start image capture activity to new method, and put it to dialog's OnClickListener:

```
builder.setMessage(geoProtip).setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            captureImage();
        }
    });


private void captureImage(){
        // start the image capture activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);        
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH, "tmpfile.jpg")));
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);        
}
```

And modify if-else:

```
if (!geoProtipAlreadyShown) {
    showGeoProtip();
    ....
}else{
    captureImage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your intent sending to the onclicklistener of one of the buttons of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic gotcha for Android programmers. Basically showing the alert does not halt the execution of the code, so you have to start the intent inside an onclicklistener.

Comment: The problem is that the alert should only be shown once (on the first start). So how can I start the intent when the dialog is not shown? Do I have to source out the intent-code to a separate method and call it both via the dialog, and in the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful

```
Dialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("TITLE")
    .setMessage("MSG")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Write the intent here.
        }
    })
    .create();
    dlg.show();
```